# Does an infinite product where each term is one of two fixed matrices chosen with the same probability converge?

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems

Let $A,B$ be linear transformations in $\mathbb C^d$ such that $|\det(AB)|<1$ and have no non-trivial invariant subspaces in common. That is, if $V$ is an invariant subspace of $A$ and $W$ is of $B$ then $V\cap W$ is either $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb C^d$. Let $X_i$ be independent random matrices defined by

$$\mathbb P[X_i=A]=\mathbb P[X_i=B]=\frac 12.$$

Is it true that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\to 0$$

almost surely as $n\to\infty$?

This question is inspired by work on [random dynamical systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.02556). Linear functions are usually the simplest, and I couldn't find anything about random linear dynamical systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been studied. See for example:

*Bellman, Richard*, [**Limit theorems for non-commutative operators. I**](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-54-02148-1), Duke Math. J. 21, 491-500 (1954). [ZBL0057.11202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0057.11202).

*Furstenberg, H.; Kesten, H.*, [**Products of random matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177705909), Ann. Math. Stat. 31, 457-469 (1960). [ZBL0137.35501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0137.35501).

*Bougerol, Philippe; Lacroix, Jean*, [**Products of random matrices with applications to Schrödinger operators**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/362752), Progress in Probability and Statistics, Vol. 8. Boston - Basel - Stuttgart: Birkhäuser. X, 283 p. DM 88.00 (1985). [ZBL0572.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0572.60001).

*Pollicott, M.*, [**Effective estimates of Lyapunov exponents for random products of positive matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6544/ac15ac),  [ZBL07384583](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07384583).